# Can't change WordPress Address (URL)

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to change WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL). after a few experiments unfortunately using wp-admin or even changing it on phpmyadmin wordpress cannot be accessed.

What I have tried:
  1. I try to change the URL in the general settings of the wordpress is still redirecting to the old url & page 404 not found.

2. Then I try in the same config.php it can't be 404

I change it in phpmyadmin (db) in the same wp_option it can't.

3. Please help, thanks, in advance

   I want to change the url as follows:
   https://example.com/spm to https://example.com/

Comment: May be you have to send the list of changes you did. any ways its may be because of wrong url on prefix_options table, .htaccess or may be its in cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You everyone, my issue solve finally.
the problem is my wordpress in subfolder on host. so when i want to change for example to root url or something else.

1. Move the root wordpress to public html
2. Move the wordpress file to Public html

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this:-

Edit **wp-config.php**

It is possible to set the site URL manually in the `wp-config.php` file.

Add these two lines to your `wp-config.php`, where **example.com** is the correct location of your site.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

**OR**

**Change WordPress URL Directly in Database**

In **phpMyAdmin**, click on your database on the left-hand side. Then scroll down and click on the **wp_options** table. If your database has a different prefix it might be named slightly different, such as **wp56_options**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for the response, I have tried with the method you have recommended. I have tried changing the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL), unfortunately both websites have redirected to the old url.